# removing duplicate dictionaries in python class

Tags: python

I am incorporating an API into a class and I've made all the various endpoints into functions. I have a base class which creates a mechanize browser object.  Each function I have repeats a lot of the same data that I encode and send in my post request. I do not want to make a dictionary for each function. Can someone give me some suggestions how I can streamline this?

Here is a sample of what I'm speaking about:

```
def make_url(host='api.funsite.com/', scheme='https'):
    return '%s://%s' % (scheme, host)

def make_post(br, data):
    print make_url()+'&'+urlencode(data)
    raw = br.open(make_url(), urlencode(data))
    return raw


class ParkLogicAPI(BaseAPI):
    def __init__(self, accountId, token, client):
        super(ParkLogicAPI, self).__init__()
        self.accountId = accountId
        self.token = token
        self.client = client

    def getDailyDataFinal(self, startDate, endDate, display='screen', format='csv'):
        data = {'accountId': self.accountId,
                'client': self.client,
                'token': self.token,
                'class': 'CustomerReports',
                'method': 'getDailyDataFinal',
                'startDate': startDate,
                'endDate': endDate,
                'display': display,
                'format': format}
        resp = make_post(self.browser, data)
        return resp

    def getDailyDataEstimates(self, startDate, endDate, display='screen', format='csv'):
        data = {'accountId': self.accountId,
                'client': self.client,
                'token': self.token,
                'class': 'CustomerReports',
                'method': 'getDailyDataEstimates',
                'startDate': startDate,
                'endDate': endDate,
                'display': display,
                'format': format}
        resp = make_post(self.browser, data)
        return resp

    def getDomainDailyDataFinal(self, date, display='screen', format='csv'):
        data = {'accountId': self.accountId,
                'client': self.client,
                'token': self.token,
                'class': 'CustomerReports',
                'method': 'getDomainDailyDataFinal',
                'date': date,
                'display': display,
                'format': format}
        resp = make_post(self.browser, data)
        return resp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract the base data out into its own method, then call that with the additional method as required like so:

```
def getBaseData(self, **kwargs):
    data = {'accountId': self.accountId,
            'client': self.client,
            'token': self.token,
            'class': 'CustomerReports',
            'display': display,
            'format': format}
    data.update(kwargs)
    resp = make_post(self.browser, data)
    return resp

 def getDailyDataEstimates(self, startDate, endDate, display='screen', format='csv'):
     return self.getBaseData(startDate=startDate, endDate=endDate,
                             method='getDailyDataEstimates',
                             display='screen', format='csv')
```

Because this merges the keyword arguments (aka. `**kwargs`) into the `data` array, this can be genericised so *any* data can be inserted into the dictionary easily, for example:

```
 def getMonthlyDataEstimates(self, startDate, endDate, display='screen', format='csv'):
     return self.getBaseData(month=getMonth(statrtDate)
                             method='getMonthlyDataEstimates',
                             display='screen', format='csv')
```

Comment: `startDate` and `endDate` do not appear to be common to all methods.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Modified so it merges `**kwargs` into the generic data and calls it.

Comment: Very nice. This way, you effectively have wrappers around my second idea, which I sort-of got from your first version. :)

Comment: This is great. Thanks guys.  One question, do you think it is better to make the actual post in the API Method function or in the _getBaseData method?

Comment: It's simpler to have it in the "base" method, because it's part of the "repeated" work across the original methods. But you want to use a better name than `_getBaseData` in this case. :) And while we're at it - I tried to quietly lead by example in my answer, but in Python we prefer `names_like_this_for_functions`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make a single method that creates the rest of the dict; then call it and insert the stuff specific to the API call you're making.

```
def _basic_data(self, display='screen', format='csv'):
    return {'accountId': self.accountId,
            'client': self.client,
            'token': self.token,
            'class': 'CustomerReports',
            'display': display,
            'format': format}

# and then, for example:
def get_domain_daily_data_final(self, date, display='screen', format='csv'):
    data = self._basic_data(display=display, format=format)
    data['method'] = 'getDomainDailyDataFinal'
    data['date'] = date
    return make_post(self.browser, data)
```

---

Another, different approach would be to expect the calling code to supply the name of the API method (along with anything else required for that call) to a single Python method. In this case, we can use keyword arguments to handle any of the other stuff that might be needed for a given call (e.g. `date` vs `startDate` + `endDate`); we don't get to validate as much this way, though. It would look something like:

```
def make_api_call(self, method, display='screen', format='csv', **kwargs):
    data = {'accountId': self.accountId,
            'client': self.client,
            'token': self.token,
            'class': 'CustomerReports',
            'method': method,
            'display': display,
            'format': format}
    data.update(kwargs)
    return make_post(self.browser, data)
```

which we can then call with something like `instance.make_api_call('getDomainDailyDataFinal', date=date)`.

Comment: If I do it this way, I'd have to know which kwargs belong to which API method.  I'm trying to figure out a way that combines both methods you mentioned.

Comment: Then you probably want to go with the (updated) other answer. :)